# Has MVC 5 Altered What Happens On Manually Set 401

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, http-status-code-401

I have a custom authorisation attribute that directs to an action on the error controller.

```
   public ActionResult Unauthorised()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return View();
    }
```

I've upgraded to MVC 5, which is redirecting to the login page, even if the user is logged in. Ie. they don't have access to this page because of their role so I redirect to the Unauthorised action says 'you don't have permission to view XXX'.

I'm sure this used to work but I've now noticed that with an upgrade to MVC5 it redirects no matter what.

Has MVC5 changed this behaviour? I can't seem to find anything saying so on Google.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the :

```
<AllowAnonymous>
```

attribute and see if that makes a difference.